# How to check string from database if it's a URL using PHP?

Tags: php

im having a problem.
I have field in my database where a user can put a facebook url. What i need to do is to check if the data is a url, parse it and just return the username after the / in the url.

An example:

if the database says https://www.facebook.com/username  just username
if says www.facebook.com/username same
if says just the username just show the username

i have tried it like this:

```
$url = $facebook;


if (strpos($url,'https://') == true){
$facebook = str_replace('https://', '', $url ); 
$facebook = substr(strrchr($url, '/'), 1);

}
else
{
$facebook = $facebook;
}
```

Comment: You could also use `explode()` and `end()` -> `$facebook = end(explode('/',$facebook));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a regular expression:

```
$username = preg_replace("/.*\//", "", $url);
```

A period matches any character and a star does a 'greedy match' for the character that precedes it, meaning it keeps matching as long as it continues to satisfy the pattern. The backslash escapes the forward slash and allows it to be used as a matching character. In plain english, the pattern matches everything up to the last forward slash on a line and stops, then replaces it with "".